# comparing one value in a column to all the values in another column at a time SQL/DB2

Tags: db2

I have three columns as shown below. What is the best way to pull all the values from column 3 that are not the same in the other columns? the result should return 2, 7 and 9 as they are only in column 3.

```
Column 1 |  Column 2  | Column 3
---------|------------|---------
1        |    5       |     1
3        |    4       |     2
1        |    5       |     7
4        |    6       |     9
```

I tried  `not in (Column 1, Column 2)` method but it checks by row only and I need it to take first value in column 3 and compare against the whole column in 1 and 2....

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `NOT EXISTS` condition for this:

```
select t1.c3
from the_table as t1
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t1.c3 in (t2.c1, t2.c1));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e20d6021a9367ae46ab3e40a6105d2ca)

Comment: if you can only select a certain range of values using a primary Key could you still use "not exists"?